# SSH: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: ssh, debian, libraries

When I test SSH locally (SSH localhost), I get the following error:

```
SSH: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyutils.so.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So it seems a lib is missing however, in aptitude the given lib (libkeyutils1) is marked as installed

Any ideas what the problem might be?

I am running this on Debian Squeeze.

Comment: aptitude operates with packages (libkeyutils1) while a shared library is a single file (libkeyutils.so.1) or a symlink. Did you check that it exists and has proper permissions at least?

Comment: Did you tamper with your LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable?

Comment: Where should I find this library? And how do I get it if it isn't there?
ssh has been freshly installed, so no settings have been changed